# In linux and solaris, what is the UUID based off of?

Tags: unix, filesystems

If you run dmidecode|grep UUID you are given a "globally unique string of characters" which can be used for licensing purposes. 
In linux, the format is usually something like this:
44454C4C-3200-1047-8047-A4D04F394F30

In solaris, the format is usually something like this:
0ab290a98

So, what is this number actually based on? Originally I thought it would be based on drive or volume serial number, but that would be odd given the differing formats (though one is zfs, the other is extN). Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure myself, but looking into the source (static void dmi_system_uuid ==> https://github.com/mirror/dmidecode/blob/master/dmidecode.c), it appears that the UUID is pulled from the SMBios memory from your motherboard.

See section 7.2.1 from the SMBios reference specification for more detail about that: http://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_2.7.1.pdf